# mongoDB: how to check existence of a dict key in a nested dict?

Tags: python, mongodb

i have a nested dict inserted in mongoDB. How to query if a specific dict path exists or not?
I am not able to query with regx on key.

E.g of dict

`dict1 = {A:{B:{C:{D:{E:1}},F:{G:{H:{L:1}}}}}`

`dict2 = {A:{B:{C:{D:{E:1}},K:{G:{S:{L:1}}}}}`

I want to verify if i have any documents with the path A.B.C.K.G.S (i am not too worried 
about S value i.e L
With example above the query should return dict2 document from mongoDB.

How can i query the same? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: db.coll.find({A.B.C.K.G.S: {$ne: null}})?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check existence, then the query you want is

db.collection.find({"A.B.C.K.G.S":{"$exists":true}})

The [`$exists` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) will return only documents which have this field, even if the value is `null`.   In contrast comparing this field for inequality to null will return documents where this field exists and is set to value other than null.  Depending on your application requirements you would use `$exists` or null comparison.

Comment: what will be faster - exists or not null? (supose all fields to be search is not null)

Comment: They’ll likely be about the same.