# How to check existence of a dictionary key in a nested dictionary when the key value is an email

Tags: mongodb, dictionary

So I found the following question and answer which is close to my issue:
[mongoDB: how to check existence of a dict key in a nested dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701414/mongodb-how-to-check-existence-of-a-dict-key-in-a-nested-dict)

The thing is, I tried for my scenario but didn't work. The key I'm looking for is an email. For example "report.stats.'some@email.com'"

How do I make this work?

And ultimately, I would like to query for multiple emails at the same time (if possible). I looked into the `$in` operator but not sure how to use it for this scenario. Probably an `$or` operator on multiple `$exists` will be the final answer.

Thank you

Comment: As I was suspecting, the dot character is reserved by MongoDB. So it must be replaced.

Comment: Please post some sample data as well as the partial query you've got already. It is impossible to guess what you have/want based on what you're disclosing so far.

Comment: Using email address as a field name feels like a design issue to me. For one, this custom-named field cannot be indexed, since it'll be different in every document in the collection. Perhaps a sub-document in the form of `{email:<email address>, value:<the field value>}` is a better solution, since it can be indexed.